# How get publish_pages permission, to post on own business Facebook page using Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am making a server-to-server Facebook 'app' so that some of the news articles we post to our own website can be posted on our own Facebook page too. I have read 14 squintillion pages of documentation, but cannot find how to get the `publish_pages` permission for myself or the app.

I have coaxed the app through the review process, and got the `manage_pages` permission allowed. I thought I had to submit all over again, to get `publish_pages` too, but the documentation says no. Apparently anyone appearing in the Roles for the app can grant the necessary permissions.

[image: My ROLES page]

I have set myself up as admin for the app, yet when trying to get a token using the Facebook developer tools, I am never shown `publish_pages`. So even if I create a non-expiring token (my end goal) it is rejected with a message about the lack of `publish_pages`.

[image: Using the EXPLORER tool]

Shouldn't I be seeing more permissions listed here?

[image: the POPUP box]

I'm sure I've read all relevant parts of the official documentation, plus StackOverflow answers and several unofficial walk-throughs, but I cannot work out what I am missing...

Answer (score 1):

> I thought I had to submit all over again, to get publish_pages too,

You do.

> but the documentation says no. Apparently anyone appearing in the Roles for the app can grant the necessary permissions.

That is for apps in dev mode. Any of those users can grant the permission to your app, while it is in dev mode. But whatever you publish through your app, will only be *visible* to this group of users only, and not to the general public.

For the content to be visible to everyone, your app needs to be in live mode.

Before you can ask people - even those with a role in the app - for `publish_pages` when your app is in live mode, you need to submit that permission for review.

Comment: The quote from the screencast documentation is `You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or by a reduced number of people.` As this is a server-to-server app, I thought this statement applied in my situation. It does not mention dev/live mode at all. It says "do not need to submit". (Which is good, because I've submitted TWICE and still not managed to get through!) At this point, I trust you more than the documentation...

Comment: Not sure what screencast you are referring to, but it might be outdated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-publish_pages says _“Requires App Review.”_ It used to be that you don’t need to submit for review if you only wanted to use this on your own pages and with users that have a role in the app - but Facebook has since tightened the rules, what with fighting fake news and all.

Comment: Do you have any advice of what should I add to my video in order to get the permission from my reviewer. They say that they want to test it, but how are they going to test it, am I supposed to give them the whole project so they can test it?
Is just ridiculous I've spent more than two hours editing video and all I want is to post to my own page from a 8 lines python script??!!